# Changing ggplot fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently have the following code to visualize my data:

```
df <- data.frame(factor = rep("myFactor", 9), 
                 filter = rep("Property Price", 9), 
                 outcome = rep("Price", 9), 
                 filter.value = c(rep("Country X", 3), rep("Country Y", 3), rep("Country Z", 3)), 
                 FactorLevel = rep(c("Bungalow", "House", "Apartment"), 3), 
                 Outcome_Variable = rep("Price",9), 
                 mean = rep(20, 9), 
                 min = rep(0, 9), 
                 max = rep(100, 9), 
                 sd = rep(5, 9), 
                 n = rep(50, 9), 
                 SE = rep(3, 9))

attach(df)

print.plot <- function (rows) {
    ggplot(rows, aes(x = FactorLevel, y = mean, fill = filter.value)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - SE, ymax = mean + SE), position = position_dodge(.8), 
                      width = 0.25)+
        geom_text(aes(label = n), vjust = 1.6, color = "black", position = position_dodge(.9), size = 3.5)   
}

print.plot(df)
```

The resulting bar chart looks like this:

[image]

How can I make the leftmost three bars all of one color (e.g. red), the center three bars another color (e.g. green), and the rightmost three bars yet another color (e.g. blue). In other words, three consecutive red bars, three consecutive green bars, and three consecutive blue bars.

Comment: To make your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as strong as possible (particularly as *minimal*), there's no need to use `attach`—it's not doing anything useful here, and it's a discouraged idiom—and there's no reason to put the plot in a function.

Comment: Good point. I actually needed to make many plots, that's why I made it a function. But for the purposes of an MCVE, I should have removed the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set fill to `FactorLevel`, and use the "group" aesthetic to control the positioning of the subgroup bars, you can achieve the effect you want:

```
df <- data.frame(factor=rep("myFactor",9), filter=rep("Property Price", 9), outcome=rep("Price",9), filter.value = c(rep("Country X", 3), rep("Country Y", 3), rep("Country Z", 3)), FactorLevel=rep(c("Bungalow", "House", "Apartment"), 3), Outcome_Variable=rep("Price",9), mean=rep(20,9), min=rep(0,9), max=rep(100,9), sd=rep(5,9), n = rep(50,9), SE=rep(3,9))

attach(df)

print.plot <- function (rows) {
  ggplot(rows,aes(x=FactorLevel,y=mean,fill=FactorLevel))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), aes(group = filter.value), color = 'white')+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - SE, ymax = mean + SE, group = filter.value),position=position_dodge(.8), 
                  width = 0.25)+
    geom_text(aes(label=n, group = filter.value), vjust=1.6, color="black", position=position_dodge(.9), size=3.5)

}
print.plot(df)
```

[image]